# WordNetLemmatizer not returning the right lemma unless POS is explicit - Python NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I'm lemmatizing the Ted Dataset Transcript. There's something strange I notice:
Not all words are being lemmatized. To say,

```
selected -> select
```

Which is right.

However, `involved !-> involve` and `horsing !-> horse` unless I explicitly input the 'v' (Verb) attribute.

On the python terminal, I get the right output but not in my [code](http://pastebin.com/midgUJ02):

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet
>>> lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> lem.lemmatize('involved','v')
u'involve'
>>> lem.lemmatize('horsing','v')
u'horse'
```

The relevant section of the code is this:

```
for l in LDA_Row[0].split('+'):
    w=str(l.split('*')[1])
    word=lmtzr.lemmatize(w)
    wordv=lmtzr.lemmatize(w,'v')
    print wordv, word
    # if word is not wordv:
    #   print word, wordv
```

The whole code is [here](http://pastebin.com/midgUJ02).

What is the problem?

Comment: Code is not working without installs ...can you extract input, e.g. how does LDA_Row look like?

Comment: It's because your POS tags are wrong. P/S: Next time, please try not to post a full code but meaning snippets in your code that explains the problem, otherwise Stackoverflow users might just try to close the question saying that the "question is unclear" or this is a "my code doesn't work" question =)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The lemmatizer requires the correct POS tag to be accurate, if you use the default settings of the `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()`, the default tag is noun, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/wordnet.py#L39

To resolve the problem, always POS-tag your data before lemmatizing, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> sent = 'This is a foo bar sentence'
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'NN'), ('bar', 'NN'), ('sentence', 'NN')]
>>> for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)):
...     wntag = tag[0].lower()
...     wntag = wntag if wntag in ['a', 'r', 'n', 'v'] else None
...     if not wntag:
...             lemma = word
...     else:
...             lemma = wnl.lemmatize(word, wntag)
...     print lemma
... 
This
be
a
foo
bar
sentence
```

Note that 'is -> be', i.e.

```
>>> wnl.lemmatize('is')
'is'
>>> wnl.lemmatize('is', 'v')
u'be'
```

To answer the question with words from your examples:

```
>>> sent = 'These sentences involves some horsing around'
>>> for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)):
...     wntag = tag[0].lower()
...     wntag = wntag if wntag in ['a', 'r', 'n', 'v'] else None
...     lemma = wnl.lemmatize(word, wntag) if wntag else word
...     print lemma
... 
These
sentence
involve
some
horse
around
```

Note that there are some quirks with WordNetLemmatizer:

- [wordnet lemmatization and pos tagging in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586721/wordnet-lemmatization-and-pos-tagging-in-python)
- [Python NLTK Lemmatization of the word 'further' with wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999273/python-nltk-lemmatization-of-the-word-further-with-wordnet)

Also NLTK's default POS tagger is under-going some major changes to improve accuracy:

- [Python NLTK pos_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)
- https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1110
- https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1143

And for an out-of-the-box / off-the-shelf solution to lemmatizer, you can take a look at https://github.com/alvations/pywsd and how I've made some  try-excepts to catch words that are not in WordNet, see https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L66

Comment: Was great help, Thanks!

Comment: Absolute spot on! Cheers!!