# NLTK lemmatization wrong result

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, lemmatization

I've use NLTK and got wrong result like this:

```
>>> print lmtzr.lemmatize('coding', 'v')
cod
```

I consider the answer is "code" instead of a fish.
Is there anyway to solve this or other python Lib can do better job?

Comment: *or other python Lib can do better job?* - NTLK is hands down the best library in its field, at least for python

Comment: Do you have the context sentence where the word occurs? Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157847/lemmatizing-words-after-pos-tagging-produces-unexpected-results/33172447#33172447. Possibly you need WSD before lemmatization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is to add the word `'coding'` to `wordnet._exception_map`:

```
import nltk.stem as stem
import nltk.corpus as corpus
wordnet = corpus.wordnet
wordnet._exception_map['v']['coding'] = ['code']
wnl = stem.WordNetLemmatizer()   

print(wnl.lemmatize('coding', 'v'))
# code
```

Note that attributes which start with a single underscore are considered private -- i.e. they are not part of the public interface. So modifying `wordnet._exception_map` as above is not guaranteed to work in future versions of nltk. (The above works with NLTK version 3.0.0. It was found by looking at the source code for [`WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/wordnet.py#L39) and [`wordnet._morphy`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1679).)

Another way to fix the problem is to modify `nltk_data/corpora/wordnet/verb.exc`. The contents of the file looks like:

```
cockneyfied cockneyfy
codded cod
codding cod
codified codify
cogged cog
cogging cog
```

if you add

```
coding code
```

then this exception is added to `wordnet._exception_map` automatically for you.

The third option, less hacky then the previous two, is to convince the developers of Wordnet to add `coding code` to `nltk_data/copora/wordnet/verb.exc`.

Comment: I think it's the `Wordnet` developers that maintain the resource and NLTK is wrapping and reading the wordnet files. Can't do much unless we convince the Princeton Wordnet people to modify their files =(