# NLTK lemmatizer changing "less" to "le". Text doesn't make sense anymore

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, text-classification, wordnet

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer.lemmatize('Less'.lower())

'le'
```

What's going on here, and how can I avoid this?

The word `'le'` is now appearing all over my LDA topic model, and it doesn't make sense.

Who knows what other words it is affecting in the model. Should I avoid using the Lemmatizer or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Lemmatization relies on correct part-of-speech tagging: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957895/wordnetlemmatizer-not-returning-the-right-lemma-unless-pos-is-explicit-python

Comment: For example, if you tag "less" as an adjective, you do get the correct answer: `lemmatizer.lemmatize('Less'.lower(), 'a')` gives `'less'`

Answer (score 0):

I will give more context in addition to the observation in comments.
They key is to **understand lemmatiziation rules**. They depend on the part of speech. Your word is considered a noun (default) and gets its **supposed plural suffix stripped** twice. Similarly as with the noun `mess` or its misspeling `mes`.

```py
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
word = 'mes'
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
wnl.lemmatize(word) # me
```

In your case, the right option is (as in the comments)

```
word = 'less'
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
wnl.lemmatize(word, 'a') # less
```

More: the rules are

```py
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordNetCorpusReader
WordNetCorpusReader.MORPHOLOGICAL_SUBSTITUTIONS
```

```
{'n': [('s', ''),
  ('ses', 's'),
  ('ves', 'f'),
  ('xes', 'x'),
  ('zes', 'z'),
  ('ches', 'ch'),
  ('shes', 'sh'),
  ('men', 'man'),
  ('ies', 'y')],
 'v': [('s', ''),
  ('ies', 'y'),
  ('es', 'e'),
  ('es', ''),
  ('ed', 'e'),
  ('ed', ''),
  ('ing', 'e'),
  ('ing', '')],
 'a': [('er', ''), ('est', ''), ('er', 'e'), ('est', 'e')],
 'r': [],
 's': [('er', ''), ('est', ''), ('er', 'e'), ('est', 'e')]}
```

For the whole algorithm, see the [source code of `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html#WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize).