# Text mining, customizing lemmatization

Tags: python, dataframe, text-mining, lemmatization

A simple DataFrame and I am applying Lemmatization to it.

Some words remained unchanged so I am looking for if a smart way to customize the Lemmatization.

```
import pandas as pd

samples = ["mike discussed the project",
       "kate visited jack",
       "tom received greetings",
       "let them discuss",
       "regular visits"]

train = pd.DataFrame(samples)

train[0] = train[0].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))

# Lemmatization
from textblob import Word
train[0] = train[0].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))

freq = pd.Series(' '.join(train[0]).split()).value_counts()

print freq.to_string()
```

The output is:

```
kate         1
them         1
the          1
visited      1
visit        1
tom          1
jack         1
let          1
regular      1
project      1
greeting     1
discussed    1
discus       1
mike         1
received     1
```

There are some words remained unchanged: visited, discussed, received
(and "discuss" was changed to "discus")

I can add on below lines before Lemmatization.

But what's the better way? Can the Lemmatization be customized?

```
# train[0] = train[0].str.replace('discussed', 'discuss')
# train[0] = train[0].str.replace('visited', 'visit')
# train[0] = train[0].str.replace('received', 'receive')
```

btw, tried NLTK's WordNetLemmatizer, it's the same. and I read [Python NLTK Lemmatization of the word 'further' with wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999273/python-nltk-lemmatization-of-the-word-further-with-wordnet) but still don't have a clue.

Comment: Out of context, the lemmatizer has no idea whether "discussed" is an adjective or a participle. Maybe you want to apply some sort of parsing to attempt to disambiguate these.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the comment. maybe some occasions it's better not to use lemmatizer.