# Why NLTK Lemmatizer can't lemmatize some plural words?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization, plural

I have tried to lemmatize a words from Quran Holy Book, but some words can't be lemmatized.

here's my sentence:

```
sentence = "Then bring ten surahs like it that have been invented and call upon for assistance whomever you can besides Allah if you should be truthful"
```

that sentence is part of my txt dataset.
as you can see, there's "surahs" which is a plural form of "surah".
I've tried my codes:

```
def lemmatize(self, ayat):
    wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    result = []

    for i in xrange (len(ayat)):
        result.append(wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(sentence[i],'v'))
    return result
```

which when I run and print, the result is like this:

```
['bring', 'ten', 'surahs', 'like', u'invent', 'call', 'upon', 'assistance', 'whomever', 'besides', 'Allah', 'truthful']
```

the 'surahs' isn't changed into 'surah'.

anybody can tell why? thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the wordnetlemmatizer per se but it just can't handle irregular words well enough. You could try this 'hack' -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333392/stemming-some-plurals-with-wordnet-lemmatizer-doesnt-work

Comment: I've tried that hack but it returns none []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

- [Stemming some plurals with wordnet lemmatizer doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333392/stemming-some-plurals-with-wordnet-lemmatizer-doesnt-work)
- [Python NLTK Lemmatization of the word 'further' with wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999273/python-nltk-lemmatization-of-the-word-further-with-wordnet)

For most non-standard English word, WordNet Lemmatizer is not going to help much in getting the correct lemma, try a stemmer:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> porter.stem('surahs')
u'surah'
```

---

Also, try the `lemmatize_sent` in [`earthy`](https://github.com/alvations/earthy) (an `nltk` wrapper, "shameless plug"):

```
>>> from earthy.nltk_wrappers import lemmatize_sent
>>> sentence = "Then bring ten surahs like it that have been invented and call upon for assistance whomever you can besides Allah if you should be truthful"
>>> lemmatize_sent(sentence)
[('Then', 'Then', 'RB'), ('bring', 'bring', 'VBG'), ('ten', 'ten', 'RP'), ('surahs', 'surahs', 'NNS'), ('like', 'like', 'IN'), ('it', 'it', 'PRP'), ('that', 'that', 'WDT'), ('have', 'have', 'VBP'), ('been', u'be', 'VBN'), ('invented', u'invent', 'VBN'), ('and', 'and', 'CC'), ('call', 'call', 'VB'), ('upon', 'upon', 'NN'), ('for', 'for', 'IN'), ('assistance', 'assistance', 'NN'), ('whomever', 'whomever', 'NN'), ('you', 'you', 'PRP'), ('can', 'can', 'MD'), ('besides', 'besides', 'VB'), ('Allah', 'Allah', 'NNP'), ('if', 'if', 'IN'), ('you', 'you', 'PRP'), ('should', 'should', 'MD'), ('be', 'be', 'VB'), ('truthful', 'truthful', 'JJ')]

>>> words, lemmas, tags = zip(*lemmatize_sent(sentence))
>>> lemmas
('Then', 'bring', 'ten', 'surahs', 'like', 'it', 'that', 'have', u'be', u'invent', 'and', 'call', 'upon', 'for', 'assistance', 'whomever', 'you', 'can', 'besides', 'Allah', 'if', 'you', 'should', 'be', 'truthful')

>>> from earthy.nltk_wrappers import pywsd_lemmatize
>>> pywsd_lemmatize('surahs')
'surahs'

>>> from earthy.nltk_wrappers import porter_stem
>>> porter_stem('surahs')
u'surah'
```

Comment: wow, thanks. this is cool. but what is "earthy" module and where can I get that? I can't call "earthy", the module's name is undefined.

Comment: `pip install -U earthy`

Comment: wow cool thanks, I have installed. is there any books or tutorial for earthy library?

Comment: There's https://github.com/alvations/earthy/blob/master/FAQ.md but if you want a more serious tool, try `spacy` https://spacy.io