# Why the stem of word "got " is still "got" instead of "get"?

Tags: python, nltk, stem

```
from stemming.porter2 import stem

documents = ['got',"get"]

documents = [[stem(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")] for sentence in documents]
print(documents)
```

The result is :

```
[['got'], ['get']]
```

Can someone help to explain this ? 
Thank you !

Comment: NIT: It's an artifact of the "stemming" library/method used - not Python, which is just the framework/runtime. The *specific library used* should thus be included in the question: is it https://pypi.org/project/stemming/1.0/?

Comment: It's one of those peculiar cases where a stemmer is not powerful enough to understand what you want. Consider lemmatizing the word first and then stemming the lemma: `nltk.WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize("got","v")` - > `"get"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a lemmatizer instead of a stemmer. The difference is subtle.

Generally, a stemmer drops suffixes as much as possible and in some cases handles an exception list of words for words that cannot find a normalized form by simply dropping suffixes.

A lemmatizer tries to find the "basic"/root/infinitive form of a word and usually, it requires specialized rules for different languages.

See

- [what is the true difference between lemmatization vs stemming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787110/what-is-the-true-difference-between-lemmatization-vs-stemming)
- [Stemmers vs Lemmatizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers)

---

Lemmatization using the NLTK implementation of the morphy lemmatizer requires the correct part-of-speech (POS) tag to be fairly accurate.

Avoid (or in fact never) try to lemmatize individual word in isolation. Try lemmatizing a fully POS tagged sentence, e.g.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk import wordnet as wn

def penn2morphy(penntag, returnNone=False, default_to_noun=False):
    morphy_tag = {'NN':wn.NOUN, 'JJ':wn.ADJ,
                  'VB':wn.VERB, 'RB':wn.ADV}
    try:
        return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        if returnNone:
            return None
        elif default_to_noun:
            return 'n'
        else:
            return ''
```

With the penn2morphy helper function, you need to convert the POS tag from `pos_tag()` to the morphy tags and you can then:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> sent = "He got up in bed at 8am."
>>> [(token, penn2morphy(tag)) for token, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))]
[('He', ''), ('got', 'v'), ('up', ''), ('in', ''), ('bed', 'n'), ('at', ''), ('8am', ''), ('.', '')]
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(token, pos=penn2morphy(tag, default_to_noun=True)) for token, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))]
['He', 'get', 'up', 'in', 'bed', 'at', '8am', '.']
```

For convenience you can also try the [`pywsd` lemmatizer](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/deep-stuff/pywsd/utils.py#L129).

```
>>> from pywsd.utils import lemmatize_sentence
Warming up PyWSD (takes ~10 secs)... took 7.196984529495239 secs.
>>> sent = "He got up in bed at 8am."
>>> lemmatize_sentence(sent)
['he', 'get', 'up', 'in', 'bed', 'at', '8am', '.']
```

---

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22343640/610569